# Cannot get item from array

Tags: php, arrays

hi im new to api calling and i seem to have a problem with getting an item called price from my array. The following is the array that I am supposed to extract price from.

```
Array
(
    [prodId] => ROC-PRD-2
    [prodName] => iphone 6
    [projectId] => 8
    [categoryIds] => Array
        (
            [0] => ROC-CAT-1
        )

    [prodParentSku] => iph6a1
    [prodMetaTitle] => iphone 6
    [visible] => 1
    [prodStatus] => 1
    [modifiedDate] => 1443472415
    [createDate] => 1443472193
    [productImages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 89
                    [imageName] => iphone-ipad hi res.png
                    [imagePath] => http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/8/products/ROC-PRD-2/iphone_ipad_hi_res.png
                    [visible] => 1
                    [featured] => 
                    [modifiedDate] => 1443472390
                    [createDate] => 1443472390
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 90
                    [imageName] => ipad 2.jpg
                    [imagePath] => http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/8/products/ROC-PRD-2/ipad_2.jpg
                    [visible] => 1
                    [featured] => 
                    [modifiedDate] => 1443472397
                    [createDate] => 1443472397
                )

        )

    [pricing] => Array
        (
            [price] => 1000
            [memberGroupPrices] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I am able to get the product images information such as id, imagepath, using the following for loop

```
foreach ( $product['productImages'] as $key => $data){
    foreach ($data as $key => $eachImage){
 }
}
```

However for price my code is as follow:

```
foreach ( $product['pricing'] as $key => $price){

}
```

If i echo the $price i would get "1000Array"
If i echo $price['price'], nothing comes out.

Comment: If there's a single field having price then you can simply use `echo $product['pricing']['price'];` instead of looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Dont need to look for `$pricing` as its its single;

```
$price = $product["pricing"]["price"];
$memberGroupPrices = $product["pricing"]["memberGroupPrices"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this

```
foreach ( $product['pricing'] as $key => $price){ 
        if($key=='price')
          $price_val=$price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just print the price with out looping

```
 $price = $array["pricing"]["price"];
```